# Ignore a script on a Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile-browser

I have a website that calls this "live chat" script in the header:

```
<script src='http://widget.rlcdn.net/widget/rl_chatwidget.js'></script>
```

However, on the mobile version of this site, the "Live Chat" widget gets in the way of the site.

Any suggestions on how to bypass a script if visited by a mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some server side logic here to add the script dinamically. You can inspect the request headers and detect the user agent. If it isn't a mobile client, add the script link with server side language, and the opposite if it's.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var ismobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

     if(!ismobile) document.write('<script src="http://source.com/script.js"></script>');
</script>
```

Source: [Hide Javascript file for mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268116/hide-javascript-file-for-mobile-devices)