# How can I hide specific javascript file for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

How can I hide a specific javascript file for mobile devices?
I use this code, but this code does not work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ismobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

if(!ismobile) document.write("<script src='http://source.com/script.js'> </script>");
</script>
```

Comment: Use this http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: Question duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268116/hide-javascript-file-for-mobile-devices

Comment: I don't ask the question is duplicated or not, I just ask the code is not working for me ok Ramesh.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get errors? Have you tested the regex outside of this code?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but it does not work. It displays the symbols ");

Answer (score 2):

Try appending the script as an element instead of writing to the document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ismobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent));

    if (!ismobile){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'test.js'; // or full url
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } 

</script>
```