# What is the best way to ignore my js and css files if mobile devices are detected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two scripts and stylesheet, one is for mobile device and another for pc.

I don't want to load the CSS stylesheet and JS file when user access from mobile or tablet devices

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ismobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

    if(!ismobile) document.write('<script src="js/PCDemo.js"></script>');
    if(!ismobile) document.write('<link href="css/PCDemo.css" rel="stylesheet" />');

    if(ismobile) document.write('<script src="js/MobileDemo.js"></script>');
    if(ismobile) document.write('<link href="css/MobileDemo.css" rel="stylesheet" />');

</script>
```

I found this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268184/7734785)

Is it good way to load the file?..

Comment: see here the answer's explaination:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508669/tell-html-doc-not-to-load-js-if-mobile-device

Comment: @לבנימלכה That answer is almost same as mine. As well as I don't want to ignore it by screen size. Because I will not change css and js design even user reduce the browser screen

Comment: I mean see those answer there are explainations about `Is it good way to load the file?..`  as I see there Your files won't load only in desktop(or whatever you want)